# NameError: name 'categorical_features' is not defined

Tags: python

I am trying to encode a categorical variable, but it gives me an error of one the arguments of the 'OneHotEncoder' function. I think this is because the argument has changed into "categories", but now I do not know how to encode this categorical variable.

This is my code:

```
#importing libraries 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np 

#importing the dataset
dataset = pd.read_csv('50_Startups.csv')
X = dataset.iloc[:, : -1].values   
y = dataset.iloc[:, 4].values


#encoding categorical data, variables that contain categories 
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder, OneHotEncoder
labelencoder_X = LabelEncoder()
X[:,3] = labelencoder_X.fit_transform(X[:, 3])
onehotencoder = OneHotEncoder(categorical_features [3] )
X = onehotencoder.fit_transform(X).toarray()

NameError: name 'categorical_features' is not defined
```

How can I manage to encode the categorical variable named 'State'?

Answer (score 1):

The variable categorical_features does not exists.

Comment: the argument 'categorical_features' has changed to 'categories = 'auto' but which arguments do I have to use if I only want to encode the third variable of my dataset?

Comment: @Majoem Your code can't be compiled. The current problem now is that `categorical_variable` isn't defined anywhere. So, I can't understand your further problems.

Answer (score 0):

The variable categorical_features does not exists. It is removed from libraries.

You can use ColumnTransformer from sklearn.compose

```
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder, OneHotEncoder
columnTransformer=ColumnTransformer([('encoder',OneHotEncoder(),[3])],remainder='passthrough')
x=np.array(columnTransformer.fit_transform(x),dtype=str)
```